# Tamaño del frame de las pestañas de una ventana

Tags: python, tkinter

no se en donde recurrir ya que estoy aprendiendo a programar con Python 3.9 por mi cuenta viendo tutoriales y leyendo sobre trabajos ajenos, pero algo que no estoy pudiendo encontrar hasta el momento es sobre la dimensiones en la hora de crear varias pestañas en un ventana con la biblioteca de tkinter, puedo cambiar el tamaño de la raiz principal, pero no puedo hacer lo mismo con el de las pestañas, por lo que si maximizo la ventana para la pantalla completa las pestañas no aumentan con la ventana, me podrian ayudar con eso, estaria muy agradecida.

0

```
'''python
ventana = Tk() 
ventana.title("MASTER PIZZA 5") 
ventana.geometry('500x300') 
ventana.iconbitmap('C:\\Users\\Yuuki\Downloads\\Nueva carpeta\\Master_Pizza_5.ico')
ventana.config(bg="orange")

rows=0
while rows < 50:
    ventana.rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    ventana.columnconfigure(rows, weight=1)
    rows += 1

control_pestaña=ttk.Notebook(ventana) # Control de pestanias
control_pestaña.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=50, rowspan=40, sticky='wens')


pesta1=ttk.Frame(control_pestaña) # Crear pestania y situarla en el control de pestanias
control_pestaña.add(pesta1, text="Pedidos") # Agregar la penstania 1

pesta2=ttk.Frame(control_pestaña)
control_pestaña.add(pesta2, text="Clientes") # Agregar la penstania 2

pesta3=ttk.Frame(control_pestaña)
control_pestaña.add(pesta3, text="Productos")

pesta4=ttk.Frame(control_pestaña)
control_pestaña.add(pesta4, text="Funcionarios")

pesta5=ttk.Frame(control_pestaña)
control_pestaña.add(pesta5, text="Reporte Diario")

pesta6=ttk.Frame(control_pestaña)
control_pestaña.add(pesta6, text= "Conexion")

'''
```

Comment: Podrias agregar el código que tienes hecho hasta ahora por favor?

Comment: Este el codigo que hice, difini la ventana y las pestañas para el

Comment: Gracias por el dato, modifique y cargue el código como me indicaste, gracias!

Comment: Utiliza `mi_widget.pack(expand=True, fill="both")`

Comment: Voy a intentarlo, muchas gracias por responder!